# PHP Problem uploading images to remote server

Tags: php

Hello could someone help me with my problem.
Im doing a basic image upload to remote server and this are my code
Local instance:

```
public function do_upload(){
    $uploadDir = FCPATH."public\\remote_files\\";

    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES[0]['name']);
    $handle    = fopen($uploadFile, "r");
    $data      = fread($handle, filesize($uploadFile));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[0]['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)){
       // set array to send data to remote server
        $remoteData = array(
            'fileName' => $_FILES[0]['name'],
            'fileData' => base64_encode($uploadFile)
        );

        // start curl set up for remote file upload
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myserver.com/folder/Rest/upload_image');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $remoteData);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        echo $response;   // set response to server.php file 
    } else {
        echo "Your file not uploaded to server.";
    }

}
```

AND HERE IS MY SERVER SIDE CODE:

```
public function upload_image(){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        if (isset($_POST['fileName']) && $_POST['fileData'])
        {
            // Save uploaded file
            $uploadDir = FCPATH."public/remote_files/";
            file_put_contents(
                $uploadDir. $_POST['fileName'],
                base64_decode($_POST['fileData'])
            );

            // Done
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
```

The image is uploaded in my local folder without any problem, i can also see something being uploaded in the remote folder but when you view the image it is broken.

It says The image “http://myserver.com/folder/public/remote_files/download.jpg” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Could anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why it is text     header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Sorry Steeve it was a mistake i copied it from one of my code i removed it and edited my post.

Comment: set this header("Content-type: image");

Comment: and you are doing mistake your header should be at the beginning of page not inside function. allow origin should be also at top add these two headers at begining of page and try

Comment: One question: In your do_upload() function you are base64_encoding the filepath? I think you should encode your $data

Comment: Andreas its not the file path but its the actual file. I am saving it temporarily to a folder and i get the image and convert it to base64.

Comment: I dont think header("Content-type: image") is needed here since im not actually viewing the image. the function is to process the remote uploading.